# How to get pid from parent perl daemon?

Tags: perl, daemon

I have some test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;

my $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new;
Proc::Daemon::Init();
my $kid_pid = $daemon->Init(
    {   work_dir     => '/home/develop',
        pid_file     => 'pid.txt',
        exec_command => 'perl /home/develop/test.pl ',
    }
);
$| = 1;

while (1) {
    my $status = $daemon->Status( [$kid_pid] );
    if ( !$status ) {
        my $kid_pid = $daemon->Init(
            {   work_dir     => '/home/develop',
                pid_file     => 'pid.txt',
                exec_command => 'perl /home/develop/test.pl ',
            }
        );
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

I need the script test.pl to know him PID. Give him a PID as an argument would be ideal, but in the arguments of Init method to give him $kid_pid ofcourse impossible. Option of reading from a file is not suitable.

And now I need to know PID of parent script. Code `my $ppid = Proc::Daemon::Init();` dont work for me, because i have loop in script and he work incorrectly. `$$` don't work too, because `Proc::Daemon::Init()` have another PID.

Comment: `exec_command => "perl /home/develop/test.pl $$"` and then `$ARGV[0]` inside `test.pl`

Comment: Question still actual, because i dont know how get parent pid from child daemon. Read from file does not suitable for me.

Comment: `$ARGV[0]` is on command line.

Comment: I wrote above, it works incorrectly for me.

Comment: parent pid i get using `ps`. Bad solution, but it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current PID with [`$$`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%24) variable, and parent PID by using [`getppid()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getppid.html).

```
perl -E 'say fork || getppid, " me:[$$]"'
7503 me:[7477]
7477 me:[7503]
```

Comment: `getppid` in test.pl return PID from `init --user` command, not PID of my parent and not him PID

Comment: `$$` work for me:)
Now I began to suspect that the parent PID also need, how to get it?)
loop in script does not allow me to use some like this `my $ppid = Proc::Daemon::Init();`

Comment: `$$` dont work now, because `Proc::Daemon::Init()` have another PID.

Comment: @Alexandr parent process exits leaving only forked daemon (which in turn becomes child of `1 init` PID).